# Can obtain the condition applied in my if conditional in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to keep in a variable the condition applied, for example:

```py
l = "test.log"
if l.endswith('.csv') or l.endswith('.log') or l.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print(someVariable)
```

> .log

```py
l = "test.csv"
if l.endswith('.csv') or l.endswith('.log') or l.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print(someVariable)
```

> .csv

How can I perform that without a switch case? I just wanna know which condition was performed.

Comment: I guess you can achieve the desired result by multiple `if ... elif ... elif ... else`.

Comment: is it always going to be file extensions? (if so, there's a good solution)...

Comment: It can be any string. I would like to perform all of this in just one line without elif or switch case

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant:

```
from pathlib import Path

def log_action():
    print("log")

def csv_action():
    print("csv")

suffix_action = {".log": log_action, ".csv": csv_action}

action = suffix_action[Path("file.log").suffix]
action()
```

this way you have a lot of flexibility to do what you want in the respective functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you only deal with file extensions, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to get the extension, and compare against a predefined set, like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

approved_extensions = {'.csv', '.log', '.xlsx'}

l = "test.log"
ext = Path(l).suffix
if ext in approved_extensions:
    print(ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if ... elif ...` like this

```py
l = "test.csv"
if l.endswith('.csv'):
    someVariable = '.csv'
elif l.endswith('.log'):
    someVariable = '.log'
elif l.endswith('.xlsx'):
    someVariable = '.xlsx'

print(someVariable)
```

Another solution might use `split`

```py
someVariable = '.' + l.split('.')[-1]

if someVariable in ('.csv', '.log', '.xlsx'):
    print(someVariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like by @Adam.Er8. But i think that the thing you want to achieve here is find the file extension. You can use `os.path.splitext`. Iıt will extract the `.log` even from path like `/path/to/file/test.log`.

```py
import os

file_path = "test.log"
file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
if file_extension in ['.csv', '.log', '.xlsx']:
  print(file_extension)
```